# Random sample related data

Tags: database, random

I'm working with a big postgres database.

I would like to use a sample of the production data as test data in my development database.

But, if I dump the production data, and randomly removes 90% of the data, I becomes very sparse. That is, the data in the tables are no longer as related as it used to be.

What techniques can one apply in order to sample the database, while keeping data related?